# How to solve error with limits in boxplot (seaborn)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

The code used to plot the box plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
ax= sns.boxplot(x = "Current_Sim_Az_obj1",y= "RUT_Distance",data = df2,whis = (0,100),meanline= True,showmeans=True)
ax.set_title('TEST 3.1 boxplot')
ax.figsize = (12, 10)
ax.set_xlabel('Current_Sim_Azimuth[°]')
ax.set_ylabel('RUT_Distance[m]')
```

The figure i received after this is [image]

Now i changed the xlimits and ylimits.The code is added below

```
pl.grid()
ax.set(xlim=(-60,60), xticks=np.arange(-60, 63,5),ylim=(3,100), yticks=np.arange(0,103,5))
```

the result was: [image]

Why this is so?The x limits are wrong.

How to solve this issue?
Also,Instead of median line in box plot i want to get a darker mean line or a point and want to remove the box(for example:something like this instead of box |-----x-----|)

Comment: The x-axis values are treated as categorical variables, whereas the x-axis range is expanded. To see why, run the following code somewhere. `print(ax.get_xticks())`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `.0` from the xticks, the easiest is to convert the corresponding column from float to integer.  Note that for boxplots (and e.g. barplots), seaborn creates a categorical axis, also for numeric data. Internally, the axis is numbered `0,1,2,...`. To change the `xlim`, you can extract the current limits and add a bit (`0.4` would be 40% of the distance between the boxes).

To "remove" the boxes, you could make them very narrow. (`width=0` would reduce them to a line). A drawback could be that also the end caps are reduced in length.

You can change the properties of the `mean` via `meanprops={...}`.  The mean is represented by a [`Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html).

Note that `sns.boxplot()` parameters that aren't [caught by seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) are sent to [`ax.boxplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot).

To change the figsize, e.g. `plt.figure(figsize=...)` can be used (to be called before creating the plot).

Here is an example. Many variations are possible.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Current_Sim_Az_obj1": np.random.choice(np.arange(-60, 61, 5.0), 1000),
                    "RUT_Distance": np.random.randn(1000).cumsum()})
df2["RUT_Distance"] += np.cos(df2["Current_Sim_Az_obj1"] / 50) * 50
df2["Current_Sim_Az_obj1"] = df2["Current_Sim_Az_obj1"].astype(int)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
ax = sns.boxplot(x="Current_Sim_Az_obj1", y="RUT_Distance", data=df2, whis=(0, 100), width=0.1,
                 boxprops={'facecolor': 'black'},
                 showmeans=True, meanline=False, meanprops={'marker': 'o', 'mfc': 'white', 'mec': 'black', 'ms': 10})
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim(xmin - 0.4, xmax + 0.4)
sns.despine(left=True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot with narrow boxes]